# What is starting this disabled service at boot? (Linux)

Tags: linux, boot, bluetooth, services

I have disabled the bluetooth service using "systemctl disable bluetooth.service", and also using systemd-manager, but it still starts at boot-time. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 amd64.

I suppose it is being activated by another service, but how can I find and stop it?

I would like to stop it from loading in the first place, rather than stop it afterwards by for example putting a line in /etc/rc.local. I also want to activate it when needed, and so not make bluetooth.service unexectuable or use similar hacks.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, another service that has a "Requires=yourservice" might cause it to start even if it's disabled.

Look for your service in the list generated by:

> systemctl list-dependencies

If you find that bluetooth is linked to another service you can edit using:

> systemctl edit --full evilbluetoothstarting.service
>
> `After=bluetooth.service`

That should create a seperate file that survives upgrades.

Now as for disabling bluetooth, you might just need to change a parameter after disabling the service:

> vim /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
>
> `AutoEnable=true`
>
> =>
>
> `AutoEnable=false`

Comment: Hi, I can't find bluetooth on the output of systemctl list-dependencies...  output is on pastebin: https://pastebin.com/iYGHZssb

Comment: It does show up though on systemd-analyze:  systemd-analyze critical-chain bluetooth.service:
 https://pastebin.com/3bWpuMtz

Comment: ...Is there any other way to investigate this? Thanks.

Comment: @LukeSharkey :  Mhh whats the output of "systemctl status PID" ? I guess you canuse "ps -ef | grep bluetooth" to get the pid, I don't actually have bluetooth :)

Comment: "Systemctl status bluetooth" showed that it was active (I didn't need to use the Process ID). Using "systemctl list-dependencies bluetooth --reverse" showed that it was being started by tlp. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Researching on internet i found out the following information:

https://geekflake.com/how-to-start-services-on-boot-in-linux/

The information explain that to elect which services start at booting process in the OPerative System 
To edit this on system has to be on /etc/init.d/ 
And has to be done with the command  chkconfig  with --add parameter or 
enable, disable using systemctl for example:

## systemctl enable bluetooth